# Restrict character/string/word in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, checkbox

My function, `addthisTxt`, is not checking the length. It should not exceed 11. Below is what I have tried so far; I'd like to keep on adding text until it reaches the max length, otherwise it should restrict the user from adding more.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbxr" value="add this offer on wrapper" 
 (change)="addthisTxt($event.target.getAttribute('txt'), $event.target.checked)">
```

**JavaScript**

```
addthisTxt(txt, checked): void {
    if (checked) {
        if((this.v.offerName.length +txt.length) >= 55){
            this.v.offerName = this.v.offerName + txt;
        }
        this.v.offerName = this.v.offerName;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the  this.v.offername ?

Comment: @R.Anandan this.v.offername has data from db. then i add dynamic text with it from UI and pls check the update code

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value on `this.v.offerName`. The UI element is not bound to this JavaScript variable and you need to set the *value* of the UI input element to restrict the value.

Comment: **not bound to this JavaScript variable** can't understand. how could i make it bound

Comment: You can use a data binding framework like knockout. Or you can simply set the value on the UI element

Comment: Checkout the tutorials here : http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections